How to export test result present in Visual Studio 2022 Professional? I am working on specflow and there is no nunit used
I have executed my tests and want to export result present in Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2022 Professional v17.10.4. I am working on specflow and there is no nunit used. Is there any way to export or capture the results from Test Explorer in any format - html or xml?

I thought that SpecFlow relies on a unit test runner. You don't need to choose NUnit, but something has to run the tests. SpecFlow even ships their own runner. Can you figure out which one is used?

What runtime does your code target? If it's .NET 6+, you should be able to use the standard .NET CLI (dotnet test ...).

I tried installing installing livingdoc using dotnet tool install --global SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI.......command.. but getting some error on the run prompt.. I tried couple times but getting same error.. kindly let know

It's. NET6 that's used ..
